# Opentracing propagation over eventbus

Tags: vert.x, opentracing, vertx-eventbus

Trying to setup java-vertx-web for opentracing Tracer, Followed the readme to complete the configuration at https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-vertx-web

Reactivated the span from routingContext which is set up by `TracingHandler` in `start()` method
using
`tracer.activateSpan(CustomTracingHandler.serverSpan(routingContext));`

At this point all the logs & traces with in route handler is working fine.

The issue of span not active re-surfaces when a message is sent on eventbus.

Tried to add interceptor to inject the headers and still the span is not active any more.

```
vertx.eventBus().addOutboundInterceptor(message -> {
        tracer.inject(TracingHandler.serverSpanContext(routingContext),
              Builtin.TEXT_MAP, new TextMapInjectAdapter(new HashMap<>()));
          message.next();
        });
 vertx.eventBus().addInboundInterceptor(
    message -> {
      tracer.extract(
          Builtin.TEXT_MAP, new TextMapExtractAdapter(new HashMap<>()));
      message.next();
    });
```

is there a way to reactivate the span on message receiver?

Comment: Hi Kiran, Can you please give an code snippet of how your are starting the span initially and which dependency your are using? I am also trying to implement vertx opentraing.

Comment: i think vertx4 has opentracing support . which vertx version are you using ? https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-tracing/tree/master/vertx-opentracing

Comment: Thanks Kiran for the link. We are using 3.5.3 version. Can't we implement tracing in this version?